# Assignment of singly-linked list in java

Tags: java

We have the following approach to merge two singly-linked list in java

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
public class Solution {
    public ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        //the next node of dummy will be pointing at the final result so it is easier to return
        ListNode dummy = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode result = dummy;
        while (l1 != null && l2 != null) {
            if (l1.val < l2.val) {
                result.next = l1;
                l1 = l1.next;
            } else {
                result.next = l2;
                l2 = l2.next;
            }
            result = result.next;
        }

        if (l1 != null) {
            result.next = l1;
        } else {
            result.next = l2;
        }

        return dummy.next;
    }
}
```

My question is after assigning dummy to result, dummy changes as result changes. This is intuitively correct because when I access the next of result, I am accessing the next of dummy.

However, for when I have an assignment like `int a = 5;` and change reassign `a = 6`, we would not get *5 == 6* apparently.

Or if I do `result = ListNode(1)`, my guess is dummy would not be changed to *ListNode(1)*.

What is the logic behind their distinctions?

Comment: Java is pass-by-value, always. That means that you can not have linkages like `first -> second -> instance`. When you do `second = first;` you have `first -> instance` and `second -> instance`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "box" metaphor for variables works fine with primitive values - imagine a box called `a`, which you put the number 5 in, then create a box called `b` and copy the 5 from `a` into that box. Now you can put a different number in `a` but box `b` still has the number 5.

This metaphor breaks down when a variable holds a reference to an object (e.g. a `ListNode`), because an object is not really the same kind of thing as a primitive value; the object itself is never stored "in" a variable. When you write code like `ListNode dummy = new ListNode(0);` you are not creating an object and storing it in a box named `dummy` - you are creating an object and storing *a reference to it* in the box named `dummy`.

For a better analogy, think of house addresses. Make a box named `dummy` and in it, put the address of your friend's house. Then make another box named `result` and put a copy of that address in the new box. Now, if your next instruction is "go to the house at the address in the `dummy` box and paint it blue", you should not be surprised that afterwards, the house at the address in the `result` box has also been painted blue; they are the same house, after all.